# Apache Airflow through HTTP

Tags: rest, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've been running into an issue where I can successfully trigger a dag from airflow's rest api command(s) (https://airflow.apache.org/api.html); however, the dag INSTANCES do not run. I'm calling -> POST `/api/experimental/dags/dag_id/dag_runs` where dag_id is the dag I'm running. The only thing that happens is that the dag immediately returns success. I trigged the dag manually and I get running dag instances (see picture 2nd dag run). Note the 2nd DAG run fails - this should not affect the issue I am trying to fix.

[DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6RuF.png)

Fixed the issue -> Had to deal with scheduler. I added 'depends_on_past': False, 'start_date': datetime(2019, 6, 1) and it got fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dag runs created outside the scheduler still must occur after the `start_date`; if there are no existing runs already you might want to set the schedule to `@once` and the start_date to a past date for which you want to have the `execution_date` run. This will give you a successful run (once it completes) against which other manual runs can compare themselves for `depends_on_past`.

Comment: My schedule is set to None (this was not the issue) since I am always externally triggering the DAG from an HTTP Request. The main issue was I had start date set to time.Now(). Thank you !

Comment: @AurelianoYepez yeah, all the examples use a relative to now datetime, because its easy for being flexible with a newly installed Airflow. However the recommendation in the docs is to always use a fixed date (can be a string) like `'2019-09-30'` https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/88989200a66291580088188f06a6db503ac823e2/airflow/models/dag.py#L251-L271

Comment: True; again thanks ! I got my source of truth through this site -> https://www.astronomer.io/blog/7-common-errors-to-check-when-debugging-airflow-dag/ under point #2 "Make sure you don't have **datetime.now()** as your start_date"